# Git pull doesn't autocommit

Tags: git, repository, commit, pull

I don't know why but anytime I pull from a remote repo, all the changes are not committed automatically.
So it's like when I do:

```
git pull origin master
```

I would have done instead:

```
git pull --no-commit origin master
```

How can I restore my pull command to the default behaviour?

Comment: So when you pull, what state is the repo in?

Comment: Does this happen always or just sometimes? Did you double check the `git status`? Maybe there was a merge conflict which needs to be manually resolved? In that case, automatic committing is impossible, regardless of settings.

Comment: It happens always on that repository, even when there are no conflicts at all.  When I pull the files are put in stage (those with no conflicts) otherwise in the modified ones (those with conflicts).

Comment: Is your pull a merge (that is, `git pull --no-ff origin master` fails), and if so, is your editor set correctly?  Does `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no git pull origin master` work?

Comment: Although this does not answer your question, I'll mention that I recommend *avoiding* `git pull` entirely. All it does is run `git fetch`, and then run a second Git command, typically `git merge` (though you can select a different second command, except that you have to decide this *before* you see what gets fetched, which is the biggest problem with `git pull`). So just run `git fetch`, inspect what came in if you want (I usually do want), then, *if it's appropriate now*, run `git merge` or `git rebase` if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout to master branch and just do git pull .
It will automatically take the latest code .

If you want latest code in a different branch, run

```
git pull origin master
```

This will take the latest code from master and merge it in your branch.
Please note that while creating a pull request in this branch, all the new changes ,which you just pulled, will be pushed automatically . To avoid that , you have to follow below steps.

(1) You have to make a dummy branch and take the latest code by git pull origin master. In master branch, run git checkout -b dummybranch

```
git checkout -b dummybranch
```

And then, in this dummy branch

```
git pull origin master
```

(2) commit and push this dummy branch to remote

```
git commit -m "dummybranch"
git push
```

(3) now from this dummybranch, do git checkout -b realbranch

That's it . This new branch is clean and its pull request wont be having extra files which you have not committed .
You can make your changes in this branch and commit, push it . Only your changes will get pushed.

Comment: Thanks, @shashank-singh for the response. this issue was so old I'm not able to verify if it can be the solution to the problem. Anyway, if somebody here would have the same issue and says it works I will flag it as the correct answer.